# Add W3C HTML5 Validator to website

Tags: html

Does anybody know how to add the W3C HTML 5 validator onto my website.(So that I have a direct link to the validator which checks my page)

Thanks

Comment: Don't bother; validators are confusing to users and simply add more bytes that take more time to load.

Comment: It is an assignment? What is the assignment? And what have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

You pass it via the URL: http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=www.google.com

I am curious as to why you would need this link on your page, though.

Comment: It's for a University Assignment, the lecturer wants a direct link to the validator so he can check it validates quikly.

Comment: That is one amazingly lazy professor. Good luck with your assignment.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work -

```
$('#validation').attr('href','http://validator.w3.org/check?uri='+window.location.pathname);


<a href="" id="validation">Validation</a>
```

**Edited** the top line - Hope that helps!

Answer (score -1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload =function () {
    var submitbutton = document.getElementById("q");
    if (submitbutton.addEventListener) {
        submitbutton.addEventListener("click", function () {

    if (submitbutton.value == 'Validate') {
                submitbutton.value = '';
            }
        });
    }
}
</script>


<div id="header">
    <form action="http://validator.w3.org/check" id="newsearch" method=
    "get" name="newsearch">
        <input class="textinput2" id="q" maxlength="120" name="uri"
        placeholder="Enter URL" size="21" type="text"> <input class=
        "button2" type="submit" value="Validate">
    </form>

    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```